# set boxplot parameters in mplstyle or matplotlibrc

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, colors, dataset

There are numerous ways to change e. g. colors of boxplot elements. However, I prefer to set them for all my plots in a dedicated .mplstyle or in my matplotlibrc. Both methods appear to not change anything for boxplots, though.

Here is part of my own.mplstyle which should set the caps to yellow:

```
# Boxplots
boxplot.capprops.color: y
boxplot.capprops.linestyle: -
boxplot.capprops.linewidth: 1.0
boxplot.flierprops.color: y
boxplot.flierprops.linestyle: none
boxplot.flierprops.linewidth: 1.0
boxplot.flierprops.marker: x
boxplot.flierprops.markerfacecolor: auto
```

and part of my matplotlibrc which should set the caps to blue:

```
boxplot.capprops.color     : b
#boxplot.capprops.linewidth : 1.0
# boxplot.capprops.linestyle : -
```

however, the following code leads to black caps:

```
plt.style.use('own')
dataset.plot(kind='box')
plt.show()
```

**figure:**

[image]

also, is there a way to set cap size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas ignores the rc settings for boxplots. They work fine however for matplotlib boxplots.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

plt.rcParams["boxplot.capprops.color"] = "red"

data = np.random.randn(20,5)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=list("ABCDE"))

fig, (ax,ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
ax.set_title("matplotlib boxplot")
ax.boxplot(data)

ax2.set_title("pandas boxplot")
df.plot(kind="box", ax=ax2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer! yay, why is that? Missing feature of pandas or is this intentional?

Comment: I would suspect someone not paying attention when writing that function. Possibly you're the first one to actually wanting to use those rc params for pandas plots. [Here is the line](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/b5d81cfe43eeccfc3641aa9578097f726da9ce9d/pandas/plotting/_core.py#L1652) that sets the color to black.

Comment: OK, this is crazy :) thanks for finding that line of code. I probably should file a bug report / feature request on github then?

Comment: You can do that of course. I would think that this is really low priority, since there is a workaround present ("use matplotlib"), but if someone has the bandwidth to fix this, they might.